# How does excel interpret an array

Tags: excel, vba

Is an array stored as a string ?

Example :

```
Arr[0]="A"
Arr[1]="B"
Arr[2]="C"
```

Is this array stored like this `"A,B,C"` if yes, it is `","` or `";"` separator ?

I've built the following function :

```
Function test(Ref As String) As Variant

Dim creationdetableau() As String
Dim cpt As Integer

cpt = 0

For i = 1 To 35500

If Ref = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CashFlows").Cells(i, "A").Value Then
    ReDim Preserve creationdetableau(cpt)
    creationdetableau(cpt) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CashFlows").Cells(i, "B").Value
    
    cpt = cpt + 1
    
    Debug.Print i
End If
Next i

test = creationdetableau

End Function
```

If I call

```
=test(A2)
```

In an excel sheet, would it print the string in ? If No how would you do ?

What Am I trying to do :

I try to use this formula

```
=CfDur(E2;P2;CashFlows!B2:B100;CashFlows!J2:J100)
```

But my goal is to replace this `CashFlows!B2:B100` by a custom vba function called `test`

=CfDur(E2;P2;test(A2);CashFlows!J2:J100)

CashFlows!B2:B100 contains date :

[image]

to conclude :

```
=CfDur(E2;P2;test(A2);CashFlows!J2:J100)
```

does not work

Comment: Look at an array as a matrix. It's iterable or you can call it's elements by their index-positions. A string is a complete different type of variable.

Comment: @JvdV I know what is an array but when a formula want array as argument, does it except `range("A:A").value` or a `string` ?

Comment: This question might be too general. What's your specific use case?

Comment: You have tagged VBA, therefor my 1st comment is targeting variables. If your question is about excel-formulae then please make that clear. But in general: No, an array is an array, and a string is a string. Two complete different things.

Comment: If you are trying to build a formula in VBA, then the array part will be a string like the rest of it. The separator will depend on your regional settings and the orientation of the array.

Comment: @BigBen I want to pass an array as argument in an excel function, so i was wondering if the input excepted was a `string` or a `range`

Comment: It'd be a `Variant`.

Comment: @Rory ok, and can a function return an array in a cell ? or do I need to directly use a string ?

Comment: A function can return an array.

Comment: @Rory thank you, I edited My post so its more clear for you

Comment: @Rory this does only return the first value of the array in sheet

Comment: Depends which version of Excel you have. If you have 365 with dynamic arrays, it will spill to return all the data. If not, you need to array enter it into multiple cells, or combine it with another function like INDEX to return specific items.

Comment: Are you trying to recreate `FILTER()`?

Comment: @Rory thank you, I did a last edit so yu fully understand my goal. How can I modify my `test` function so it works ?

Comment: This is like trying to hit a target that's in perpetual motion. It depends on what kind of argument the function you are calling expects.

Comment: @Dorian what version of excel do you have.  What is going to happen with older versions is that the first element in the array will be put in the cell in which the formula is placed.  A cell can only hold one element.  If you have the dynamic array formula in Office 365 Excel then it will spill the array across with one element per cell

Comment: @Rory it except an `array`

Comment: If it expects an array then have your function return an array.

Comment: @ScottCraner Im working on excel 2016

Comment: @Rory but `CfDur(E2;P2;test(A2);CashFlows!J2:J100)` does not work

Comment: If it allows arrays in the third criterion it will expect an array of the same size in the forth.  so you will need to filter the values in column J on the same conditional as column B

Comment: @ScottCraner but I have same size in my array and CashFlows!B2:B100 (they both contain 99 date)

Comment: Now you're expecting us to hit a target we can't even see - namely your `CfDur` function.

Comment: @Dorian but `test(A2)` will return a smaller number of elements than `99` but `CashFlows!J2:J100` will still return `99`

Comment: @ScottCraner exactly so How do I modify `test` so it returns the 99 value ?

Comment: you can't, YOu would create a second one the filters Column J on the same criteria and use that in the forth criterion of you formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner but this only work in 1 case ? For exemple if I have 2 Line :

=CfDur(E2;P2;test(A2);CashFlows!J2:J100)
=CfDur(E3;P3;test(A3);CashFlows!J100:J200)

The list of date will not be the same ..

Comment: I now agree with @rory this is an ever moving target.  I am out.

Comment: @ScottCraner so you have no Idea of how I can work arround ? :'(

Comment: @ScottCraner Well I did manage to found how to solve this, Got to pass by the API and to execute the formula directly in VBA

Answer (score 1):

They are not "stored" as a `String`, but as distinct elements that can be indexed or retrieved by iteration. For example:

```
Sub Dorian()
    Dim Arr(0 To 2) As String, i As Long
    
    Arr(0) = "A"
    Arr(1) = "B"
    Arr(2) = "C"
    
    For i = 0 To 2
        MsgBox Arr(i)
    Next i
    
    For Each a In Arr
        MsgBox a
    Next a
    
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

The elements of an array can be numbers or Pictures or Ranges or most other types of Objects.

Comment: The inverse is true: A string is an array of char. So it's a backwards question. If you make an array of char then yes, you've made a string in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The receiving function will read the passed variable according to the data type of the array used to pass it:

```
Dim arrInt() as Integer
Dim arrStr() As String
```

Note: `Dim arrVar as Variant` and `Dim arrVar() as Variant` will yield the same result.

The built in `Array` method expects variant data.

A variant parameter will accept almost any data type passed to it, provided it can be parsed, so for max compatibility you could use variant in your function parameters.

For performance or safety use specific data types instead and ensure the arrays used are of the appropriate type.

You can make an array from all basic data types and many object types too. If you can't find an array type to suit use `System.Collections.ArrayList`,

Comment: A Variant and an array of type variant are not the same thing and are not always interchangeable.

Comment: Sounds sensible but *solely* in terms of accepting parameters I can't think of an example.. can you give one please? The errors it could cause down the line aside.

Comment: It wasn't really clear to me what you meant by your comment. It appeared to say that they were interchangeable, which would imply that using a variant in the calling routine when the called function expected an *array* of type variant would work, but it won't (though it would the other way round of course).

Comment: Just so, I meant if the variable and the parameter were both variant but contained an array, or the variable was variant array and the parameter was variant